Chrome extension Minified React error #418
I built a chrome extension used on ChatGPT website, recently I notice the extension does not render correctly, I could not find the inserted component with class "my-container" and all styles got lost, although I have not updated it.
It gives error of "Minified React error #418". In the error link, it says "It can also happen if the client has a browser extension installed which messes with the HTML before React loaded.", I tried to search online but have not found a solution yet. I appreciate it if you have any suggestions!
Below is my code
const root = document.createElement("div");
root.className = "my-container";
const element = document.body.querySelector("div div");
element.appendChild(root);
const rootDiv = ReactDOM.createRoot(root);

rootDiv.render(<React.StrictMode>test</React.StrictMode>);

console error
